# When I teleport a container (e.g. a chest or bag), do the contents go with it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, targeting

The [*teleport*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport) spell allows one to teleport an object:

> This spell instantly transports you and up to eight willing creatures of your choice that you can see within range, or **a single object that you can see within range**, to a destination you select. If you target an object, it must be able to fit entirely inside a 10-foot cube, and it can't be held or carried by an unwilling creature.

Suppose I want to send a chest full of items to someone far away. **If I cast *teleport* on the chest to send it to them, do the contents go with it, or do they stay behind and spill out onto the floor where the chest used to be?**

Does the answer change if, instead of a mundane container, I use a [bag of holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding)?

Comment: **Historical note:** Ah, the ol' teleporting-a-bag-of-coins question. No previous edition of Dungeons and Dragons explicitly answers this question, so generations of dungeon masters have had to come up with their own answers.

Comment: Personally, the wording of this question seems more clear to me, so at the least I'm glad you asked it so it can serve as a signpost. :) ...That said, I think you could easily make this *not* a duplicate by just editing your question to focus on the Bag of Holding case. (Though you could also more generally ask what happens to carried items when the *teleport* spell is used, since that doesn't seem to be covered by an existing question.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your edit until after I accepted the duplication. Maybe I'll ask those separately at some point.